# How can i Tansfer this sql syntax to linq?

Tags: sql, linq

```
SELECT t0.SHOPID, 
       t0.CONSGIPOS,
       t1.StoreName as CStorename,
       t0.ORDPOS,
       t2.StoreName as OStoreName
FROM EC_ORDER t0
LEFT JOIN HIERARCHY t1
  ON (t0.CONSGIPOS = t1.STOREID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN HIERARCHY t2
  ON (t2.STOREID = t0.ORDPOS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty` for left joins in `LINQ`. Try this:

```
var result = (from t0 in context.EC_ORDER
               join t1 in context.HIERARCHY on t0.CONSGIPOS == t1.STOREID into t1tmp
                from t1t in t1tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join t2 in context.HIERARCHY on t0.ORDPOS == t2.STOREID into t2tmp
                from t2t in t2tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select {
                         t0.SHOPID, 
                         t0.CONSGIPOS,
                         CStorename = t1t != null ? t1t.StoreName : null,
                         t0.ORDPOS,
                         OStoreName = t2t != null ? t2t.StoreName : null
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks,  i modify to this, it,s work too .

 from p in EcOrders
 join t1 in Hierarchies on p.Consgipos equals t1.Storeid into t1tmp
 from t1t in t1tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join t2 in Hierarchies on p.Ordpos equals t2.Storeid into t2tmp
 from t25 in t2tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
 
 select new 
 {
     p.Shopid,
  p.Consgipos,
  CStoreName=t1t.Storename,
  p.Ordpos,
  OStoreName =t25.Storename
  
 
 }